# C - Binary Search Tree's Initial Insertion is NULL

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I wrote this binary search tree data structure but I can't seem to figure out why or how the first node being printed is ZERO (0).

My code is [publicly accessible here](http://ideone.com/SF8uuB) on ideone

```
void insert_tree(tree **l, int x, tree *parent)
{
    tree *p;       /* temp pointer */

    if (*l == NULL) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(tree));
        p->item = x;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
        p->parent = parent;
        *l = p;     /* link into parent's record */
        return;
    }

    if (x < (*l)->item)
        insert_tree(&((*l)->left), x, *l);
    else
        insert_tree(&((*l)->right), x, *l);
}
```

I think my confusion lies in the indirection and use of pointers (and pointer to pointer). I understand there are other ways to go about it but I am trying to stick with this particular use of pointers for good reason.

Comment: in your code(Line 69), you didn't do anything to initialize the root node, it's a block of uninitialized memory

Comment: What is to happen if `x == (*l)->item`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are adding an empty node in the `main`, without initializing its `item`, `left`, or `right`: when you do this

```
tree *root = malloc(sizeof(tree));
```

the `root` gets assigned an uninitialized chunk of memory. You could place the first element into the first element directly, but this is not necessary: your insertion code already handles the situation when the `root` is `NULL`.

When you change your code to assign `root` a `NULL`, like this,

```
tree *root = NULL;
```

your program works correctly ([demo](http://ideone.com/Q8RwOZ)).